# Why is the Image Sensor Board routing different?

Tags: camera, pcb-assembly, routing, imageprocessing, image-sensor

The below posted is a open source camera project [Elphel](https://www.elphel.com/) PCB layout images

I have took their  353 model camera, which is mounted with an Onsemi sensor

I only know that for high speed signals we go for curved traces to avoid reflections ,in this case i see the complete card routed with curved traces with out any kind of angular bend

[image]
[image]

Not only this card i also have seen few image sensor boards from fairchild and omnivision having routing done with curved traces than angular, why so ?

Comment: Curved traces show no practical benefit over 90 degree and 45 degree corners for excessive reflections up to a few GHz (see http://www.ultracad.com/articles/90deg.pdf) - in this case it appears to be driven by space constraints and the location of the interconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Answered by the Elphel Maker Andrey

> The 45 degree directions were made by the ancient software that could
>   not work with arbitrary angles. Generally parallel traces have more
>   crosstalk than the ones with "random" angles. Except, of course
>   controlled impedance differential pairs, but they are parallel only to
>   each other, and not to the other pairs.
>
> All modern boards use random angles where possible.
>
> Andrey